# Describe the multiplication in the ring $F[x]/(x^2)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

Describe the multiplication in the ring  $F[x]/(x^2)$.

Is this a field?

What type of element is $[x]$.

I'm learning about field extensions and I have a general idea of what is happening but I'm having trouble working with the elements and the notation.

So for the first part, I would describe this as, we take $a,b \in F[x]/(x^2)$. Then $a \times b$, I think would be $a^2 \times b^2 = (ab)^2 \in F[x]/(x^2)$. I'm not entirely sure what is being asked here.

For the second part, we already know $F[x]/(x^2)$ is a ring and all we have to do is show multiplicative commutativity, identity, and inverse. But I don't know how to do this because as stated before, I don't know what elements of this should look like like.

Finally I don't understand what is being asked by type of element.

Any help proceeding further is appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have completely missed the operations on $F[x]/(x^2)$. You may want to backtrack in your book and look for the definition of quotient ring.

Comment: Since you are quotienting by the ideal generated by $x^2$, you have $x^2 = 0$ in this ring.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli So looking up the definition, I have that $\forall a,b \in F[x]/(x^2)$, $(a + x^2) + (b + x^2) =  (a+b) + x^2$ and  $(a + x^2) \times (b + x^2) =  (a \times b) + x^2$. Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct. But to make it more intuitive, try to come up with the generic "form" of a representative of the coset $a+(x^2)$. If you start with a random polynomial $a \in F[x]$, what is a "canonical" or "simple" polynomial which is in the same coset?

Comment: @Nick I think that is where my lack of understanding is. I don't understand what the simple polynomial should look like. Should it just be $x^2$?.

Comment: See Bernard's answer below. For example, if I start with $2+3x+4x^2+8x^3+7x^4 \in F[x]$, then the "simple" polynomial would be just $2+3x$. This is because $x^2=0$ in the quotient.

Comment: I get it. So every simple polynomial will be of the form $a+bx$. So this would be an element of $F[x]/(x^2)$? @Nick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47735/discussion-between-nick-and-nid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Modulo $(x^2)$, the ideal generated by $x^2$, all polynomials are represented by some (unique) linear $a+bx$ since $x^k\equiv 0$ for $k\ge 2$. In particular the product of two such elements is given by
$$(a+bx)(a'+b'x)=aa'+(ab'+a'b)x.$$
In this ring the inverse of an element $a+bx$, if it has one, is the  element $t+ux$ such that
$$at+(au+bt)x=1\iff \begin{cases}at=1\\au+bt=0\end{cases}$$
This shows $a+bx$ is invertible if and only if $a\ne 0$. It's easy to check that necessarily,
$$t=a^{-1},\quad u=-a^{-2}b,\quad\text{so that}\quad (a+bx)^{-1}= a^{-1}-a^{-2}bx.$$

Comment: @Christian Blatter: Why, yes, I said it at the very beginning. All computations take place in the quotient ring.