# Describe the multiplication in the ring $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+x+1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

Describe the multiplication in the ring $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+x+1)$. What is the multiplicative inverse of $[x]$?

To figure this out, I found that $x = -\frac {1}{2} + i \sqrt {\frac{3}{4}}$. So there clearly aren't any real solutions to this. But I am trying to figure out what elements of this ring look like in order to find an inverse and to see what multiplication looks like. I am new to field extensions and am a little confused as to how to work with them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992447/describe-the-multiplication-in-the-ring-fx-x2) is very relevant.

Comment: My bad, I thought you wanted the inverse of any element, which is a little more complicated

Comment: @SpamIAm I tried using that to do this and I know that I need a general form of the polynomials in this quotient ring but I don't know what they should look like. I also understand that we should treat $(x^2 + x + 1)$ as  $0$. I'm just confused on how to do these types of problems generally.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have 
$$
x^2 + x +1 = 0
$$

you see that

$$
1 = - x^2 - x = x (- x -1)
$$

so

$$
x^{-1} = - x - 1
$$

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to think about it.

The first is quite literal. The elements of $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^2+x+1)}$ are residues of polynomials, $\overline{f(x)}$. In this ring $\overline{f(x)} = \overline{g(x)}$ if and only if $f(x)-g(x)$ is divisible by $x^2+x+1$.

To multiply $\overline{f(x)}$ and $\overline{g(x)}$, multiply them as polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then divide by $x^2+x+1$ and take the remainder.

---

Another way: $$\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^2+x+1)} \cong \{a+b\alpha |\ a,b \in \mathbb{Q}, \text{ and } \alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0 \}$$

$\alpha$ is some "thing" that satisfies the polynomial $x^2 + x +1$. Then multiplication becomes:

\begin{align*} (a + b\alpha)(c + d\alpha) &= ac + (ad + bc)\alpha + bd\alpha^2\\
&= ac + (ad + bc)\alpha + bd(-\alpha - 1)\\
&= (ac-bd) + (ad + bc - bd)\alpha.
\end{align*}

---

Per user1952009's suggestion:

How could we express $\alpha^3$ and $\alpha^4$ as something of the form $a+b\alpha$?

\begin{align*}
\alpha^3 &= \alpha \alpha^2\\
&= \alpha(-\alpha-1)\\
&= -\alpha^2 - \alpha\\
&= 1.
\end{align*}

In this cool turn of events, we see that $\alpha^3 = 1$. Another way to see that this would happen is that $x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ and since $\alpha$ satisfies $x^2+x+1$, it will then satisfy $x^3-1$.

From this we see that $\alpha^4 = \alpha$ and in fact for $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$
\alpha^n = \begin{cases}
1 \ &\text{ if } n \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\
\alpha \ &\text{ if } n \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \\
-1 - \alpha \ &\text{ if } n \equiv 2 \pmod 3
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: For the multiplication, it is useful to write the reduced value of $x^3$ and $x^4$

Comment: Ok. So every polynomial of this ring is of the form $a+b \alpha$ because you can reduce every polynomial of higher power to this form? Also, I don't understand how the ring being isomporhic to the set you described allows us to determine what the multiplication looks like. Since $a+ b \alpha$ is an element of the set, not the ring.

Comment: @Nid The set with the multiplication desribed is a ring that is isomorphic to the one you asked about. So it is another way to think about the ring. If you take $f(x)$ and look at its remainder under division by $x^2+x+1$, you get something of the form $a + bx$. The multiplications of two things of this form and then subsequent taking of remainder modulo $x^2+x+1$, is the multiplication that I wrote down in the second part.

Comment: Ok so it doesn't affect the answer. I guess I am confused because it seems like a lot of the rings in my book from this section end up being in this form and it seemed like I was wrong in thinking this.

Answer (score 1):

The ring in question is in fact an algebra over the rationals. As a vector space one can represent the multiplication with $x$ as a matrix with respect to the basis $\{1, x\}$. We have that $x : 1\mapsto x$ and $x: x\mapsto x^2 = -x-1$, so the multiplication by $x$, as a linear transformation can be written as the matrix $$M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$ Note that $M$ satisfies $M^2+M+I = 0$ (with $I$ the identity matrix), and that the minimal polynomial of $M$ is $x^2+x+1$. The ring is now expressed as the $2$ dimensional matrix algebra generated by $M$ with basis $\{I, M\}$. The inverse of $x$ is expressed by $$M^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix} = (-1).I + (-1).M$$ In this manner the inverse of any element $a.I +b.M$ of the ring can be calculated. Note that the first column gives the coefficients of the element w.r.t. the basis. Note that these statements can be restated for higher degree polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of this ring are of the form $a+bu$ with $u^2=-u-1$ and $a,b\in\mathbb Q$.

Therefore, $(a+bu)\cdot(c+du)=(ac-bd)+(bc+ad-bd)u$.